# how to change Lufthansa seat assignment upon/after check-in when first flight is on United

Tags: check-in, seating, united-airlines, lufthansa

I am flying LH from ORD to MUC. However, my first flight to ORD is on UA. I wonder how I can select seats when I check in on UA. I got checked in for the first segment, but I can not figure out what to do after that. Is there a number I can call? It is a UA ticket, and if it matters, the booking class is H. I would like to select seats as soon as possble to get a desirable seat but I can not figure out how to do this.

Comment: UA should give you the LH reservation number with which you can then check in on LH site

Comment: Thanks! I have the LH booking reference number but it does not allow me to make seat selections because it says check-in happens through UA.

Comment: When is your flight? The check-in window may open at different times for the various flights. But I’m quite surprised you were able to check-in just for the first flight. Do you have a stopover in ORD (I.e. you’re spending a night or more there, will retrieve your bags, etc.) or is this just a connection?

Comment: My flight is this evening. No, I have a 55 min connection, and now I have noticed that they have issued seats and the boarding pass. But I was not able to select (and now change) seats.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, not a new issue on LH/United codeshare flights. See [this older question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81340/seat-reservation-for-lufthansa-flight-booked-on-united?rq=1).